# line Drawing in java

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, line

There are number of problems with this code

```
public class LineEx extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener,MouseListener{
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    public LineEx(){
        JLabel image=new JLabel("");
        JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();

        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
        int r=chooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
        File file=chooser.getSelectedFile();
        if(r==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try {
                BufferedImage bf;
                bf = ImageIO.read(file);
                ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(bf);
                image.setIcon(icon);
                image.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LineEx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(image);
        getContentPane().add(jsp);
        image.addMouseListener(this);
        image.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        this.pack();
    }
    public static void main(String ar[]){
        LineEx line=new LineEx();
        line.setVisible(true);
        line.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        x1=e.getX();
        y1=e.getY();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "X1="+x1+"  Y1="+y1);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D gd=(Graphics2D)g;
        gd.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Line2D line=new Line2D.Double(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        gd.draw(line);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x2=e.getX();
        y2=e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

1. MouseEvents are not getting exact co-ordinates that means whenever i draw a line it is not on its position. What is the reason behind this?
2. I want to move line along the image when scrollbar goes up and down, how can i do that?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g){` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){`

Comment: @mKorbel  That is where the `@Override` notation comes in very handy.  If you try your suggestion in the OP's code, it will cause a compile error.  And *that* is where an SSCCE comes in handy.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson hmmm you are right, my comment was wrong there is painted to the RootPane, but this issue paintComponent inside paint could causing freeze or filckering,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - MouseEvents are not getting exact co-ordinates that means whenever i draw a line it is not on its position. What is the reason behind this?
> - I want to move line along the image when scrollbar goes up and down, how can i do that?

You are getting the correct coordinates from the `JLabel` but paints on the `JFrame`. And the frame coordinates begins at the top left point and "includes" the window title/border.

Override the `paintComponent` method on the `JLabel` and it you will get the correct insets and coordinates.

---

**Example:**

```
class ImageComponent extends JComponent 
        implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private final BufferedImage img;
    private Point p1, p2;

    public ImageComponent(URL url) throws IOException {
        img = ImageIO.read(url);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), this);
        if (p1 != null && p2 != null)
            g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
    }
    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        p1 = e.getPoint();
    }
    @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseReleased(e);
    }
    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        p2 = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }
    @Override public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

**Test code (generates this screenshot):**

[image: screenshot]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final URL lenna =
        new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png");

    final ImageComponent image = new ImageComponent(lenna);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(image));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I didn't have added mouse listener to the `JFrame`, instead i've added it on `image(JLabel)`.

Comment: Also added a full example and a screenshot.

Comment: Here, in this program first image is initialized, can i initialize image after the frame load?
That means, the frame should be first loaded and then when i click on a button it ask me for a image then then it can be see image on frame?

Comment: Of course, either you add the component to the frame after you load the image or you handle a `null` value.

Comment: @ParthSoni: That is really a new question, but here is a full example: http://pastebin.com/nu5hT2cq

Comment: thanks man... :) BTW, you can put your answer over [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309722/add-actionevent-in-swing/9309860)

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't extend anything (especially not `JFrame`).
2. Keep a reference to the original `BufferedImage` that was loaded.
3. When a mouse event occurs (on the label, as mentioned by others), paint the line to a *copy of the image*, which is then used for the label.
4. Put the label in a panel with `GridBagLayout` with no constraint, so it is centered.
5. Drop the panel into a scroll pane that is then added to some constraint (e.g. `BorderLayout.CENTER`) of a parent component.

Note that you might also add the line objects to an expandable collection such as an `ArrayList` or [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html), then display them in a `JList` to the `WEST` of the image scroll pane.  This would make it easier to manage (and potentially delete) groups of lines.

Answer (score 2):

1. The source could be insets of JLabel's border.
2. You have the visible rect. Add visible rect x and y to your basic coordinates.