# ImageComponent Class

Tags: java, image

i have small problem with ImageComponent Class. I can't find it . How to import that class ? I'm trying to compile the sourcecode from [line Drawing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290977/line-drawing-in-java) . Any ideas ? Thx for help

Comment: The `ImageComponent` class in that link is user-defined. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: damn, sorry it's too late for thinging for me :) haha, u r right ... thx

Comment: That's alright. Delete this question since you don't need help on this anymore.

Comment: Any ideas how to save that lines ? Any time i print new line the other one dissapeare .

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `super.paintComponent(g)`? (which you should). That is what clears the frame each time. Place your lines in an ArrayList. Check out the answer here to see how that might work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13830694/1105759